# Pronunciation symbols of the American Heritage Dictionary

Tags: pronunciation, dictionaries

The American Heritage Dictionary describes pronunciation with symbols unfamiliar to me. Do Americans have no difficulty reading these symbols, which are so different from IPA’s?

[image]
: [American Heritage Dictionary](http://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=lieutenant&submit.x=-720&submit.y=-210)

Comment: @snailplane These two comments seem to me to comprise an entirely satisfactory and very useful Answer.

Comment: @StoneyB Okay, I've turned them into an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a guide to AHD symbols online: http://www.ahdictionary.com/application/resources/misc/pronkey.pdf

Most Americans can't read IPA. In grade school, I was taught symbols similar to those used by the AHD, and I didn't encounter the IPA until I was an adult.